# tasklist show all windows

Tags: windows, vbscript, cmd, tasklist

I am running the following batch script:

```
@echo off
tasklist /nh /fi "Windowtitle eq Export to PDF - DOORS" | find /i "Export to PDF - DOORS" >nul && (
echo PDF is running
) || (
echo PDF is not running
)
```

This only echos "PDF is running" if the window is currently active. Perhaps I am using the wrong command (tasklist). Is there a way to find in the full list of open windows?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This site is for programming questions only, so unless you have one (which does not seem to be the case), your question is off topic.

Comment: I don't think this is possible with the built-in tools without writing some code. If you know VBScript, you could call the `GetWindow` API function, and invoke your script with wscript. You might be able to adapt this script: http://www.vbforums.com/archive/index.php/t-500588.html

Comment: tasklist lists process. But you are interested in windows. Windows are not the same as processes. So you probably do want to do some programming.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: It will list windows, with the proper switches as used. See [TechNet reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730909.aspx) for details.

Comment: I have seen all the reference information on the `tasklist` command, and for each process, `windowtitle` is the current active window. If there is more than one window for the process it doesn't show them all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to get what I needed with a VB Script (Thanks @JoshGuzman for the idea):

```
Set Word = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set Tasks = Word.Tasks

For Each Task in Tasks
  If Task.Visible Then
    If Task.name = "Export to PDF - DOORS" Then
      Wscript.Echo "PDF is Running"
    Else 
      Wscript.Echo "PDF is not Running"
    End If
  End If
Next

Word.Quit
```

Then call the VB script with `wscript myScript.vbs` from the command prompt or a batch file.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to use Microsoft's PowerShell instead of cmd.exe (it also works on my old Windows XP, I just had to install it manually; on newer Windows versions it is preinstalled), you can install [WASP](http://wasp.codeplex.com/) as a snap-in and then do this:

```
Select-Window | Format-Table processid,processname,title -AutoSize

AUSFÜHRLICH: Enumerating all windows

ProcessId ProcessName  Title
--------- -----------  -----
     7452 powershell   Windows PowerShell V2 (CTP3)
     2688 chrome       cmd - tasklist show all windows - Stack Overflow - Google Chrome
     2688 chrome       List all open window titles - PowerShellCommunity.org - Windows PowerShell Discussion Forums ...
     3572 TOTALCMD     Total Commander 8.0 - Scrum-Master.de  Inh. Alexander Kriegisch
     4152 eclipse      Java - dummy2/src/de/scrum_master/aop/log4j/Log4jAspect.aj - Eclipse Platform - Java, Scala, ...
     5608 Foxit Reader quick5A4.pdf - Foxit Reader
     2812 TextPad      TextPad - [C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\Robin\Eigene Dateien\java-src\dummy2\bin\log4j.prop...
```

As you can see, both chrome windows are listed whereas the on-board command `Get-Process` only lists one window per process, just like `tasklist` in `cmd.exe`:

```
Get-Process | Where {$_.mainwindowtitle} | Format-Table id,name,mainwindowtitle -AutoSize

  Id Name         MainWindowTitle
  -- ----         ---------------
2688 chrome       cmd - tasklist show all windows - Stack Overflow - Google Chrome
4152 eclipse      Java - dummy2/src/de/scrum_master/aop/log4j/Log4jAspect.aj - Eclipse Platform - Java, Scala, Aspec...
5608 Foxit Reader quick5A4.pdf - Foxit Reader
7452 powershell   Windows PowerShell V2 (CTP3)
2812 TextPad      TextPad - [C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\Robin\Eigene Dateien\java-src\dummy2\bin\log4j.properties]
3572 TOTALCMD     Total Commander 8.0 - Scrum-Master.de  Inh. Alexander Kriegisch
```

Comment: The problem with that is I would have to install PowerShell on all my users machines. I need a native windows method.

Comment: It is only a problem if those users still are on XP. I guess since Vista PowerShell should be preinstalled.

Comment: Then I pray for you that they all have XP Pro because on Home there is not even tasklist.exe. I guess one way or another you will end up installing something. I do hope I am wrong though. Maybe you find something. :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution...

```
@echo off
tasklist /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq Export to PDF - DOORS" | find /i "Image Name" >nul && (
echo PDF is running
) || (
echo PDF is not running
)
```

This is what happens

```
tasklist /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq myscript.bat - Notepad"
```

If **tasklist** found any matches then will output:

```
Image Name                     PID Session Name        Session#    Mem Usage
========================= ======== ================ =========== ============
notepad.exe                   3212 Console                    1     22,704 K
```

So you have to use **find /i "Image Name"** because **Image Name** will appear if **myscript.bat - Notepad** Windows Title  exist.

Oh, I almost forgot if not find matches then the output would:

**INFO: No tasks are running the specified criteria Which match.**

Note that the Words "**Image Name**" isn't in this output.

Hope this help you.

Comment: This is a good point regarding the used method of finding the right process. However, I think it's secondary to the main problem of inability to find the process when the sought-for window exists but is not the active one *within that process*.

Comment: @AndriyM the main problem is to know if an specific window title exist and with that code is solved. This solution echos "PDF is running" even if the window if not active.

Comment: I already ran it when I knew that the window was open and it did not find the process. It doesn't seem like it is searching through all of the windows open by the process, only the active one.

Comment: I don't know what program @Jaambageek is using in this case but I was able to reproduce the issue for LibreOffice. I opened two documents, then started switching between the two windows, every time issuing two `windowtitle eq ...` requests, one per window. And every time only one or the other of the requests succeeded, never both.

Comment: @Jaambageek a vbs script it's allowed ? or you really need this via cmd only ?

Comment: @JoshGuzman VBScript may be fine if it works for what I am trying to do. Post an example and I will try it out.

Comment: @JoshGuzman, I am giving you the bounty since your VB Script gave me the idea for the solution I came up with. Thanks!